# What would be a good SE site to ask a question about building a wooden bike jump?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

So in my run through the list of SE sites, I was able to narrow down my options to just a few. I want to ask a question asking for advice finding a good design to build a wooden bike jump off of. The two best options that I can think of would be (pun intended) Woodworking and Bicycles SE. Is there a better option that I missed? Which of the two is more fit for that type of question?

Comment: Are you just looking for a design or for advice about actually building a design?

Comment: @Catija probably just finding a good design. I know this seems like this should eliminate woodworking completely, but I also want to know what kind of wood to buy, what tools I need etc.

Comment: _Maybe_ [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (they have a “Carpentry and woodworking” bullet point in their on-topic guide).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, the problem is, that on most sites, just finding a design (or a book or a guide video or a recipe) is going to be off topic. This includes on [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions falling strictly into the categories listed below are considered **off-topic**. [...]
>
> - Help finding woodworking plans

You can read more about it on their meta: [Should we allow questions that specifically ask for plans to build something?](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-we-allow-questions-that-specifically-ask-for-plans-to-build-something)

Similarly, the [Bicycles help center](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has the statement:

> Questions seeking **product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic** because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

The other things you want to ask are likely on topic on Woodworking - things like choosing a wood for a specific application, what tool you need to do a specific thing.

> Questions about the following topics are considered on-topic:
>
> - Tools, materials, or techniques used in woodworking.
>
>   - Tools may be general types of tools or specific products, including the tools themselves, as well as jigs, fixtures, safety gear, and tool accessories. Software that is used in the design of woodworking projects, such as SketchUp or AutoCAD, may also be considered a tool.
>   - Materials may include any materials commonly used in woodworking projects, including wood, composite materials, hardware, fasteners, and supplies such as sandpaper and glue. Questions about materials may also include questions about selecting materials appropriate to the project and general advice on how to locate and purchase said materials.
>   - Techniques may apply to any phase of a woodworking project, including design, prototyping, cutting, construction, finishing, safety, and fixing mistakes.

So, my recommendation to you is to go find a design for the ramp you want to make, then go to Woodworking to get help actually building it.

If you're looking for help knowing what to look for in a design for a ramp - what makes for a good homemade ramp - that might be on topic on Bicycles, as there are likely some people who know what to look for but do avoid asking for the plan itself. Don't forget, you can always check out the Bicycles chat room or meta site to get help crafting a question - they may even have some suggestions for you to try out in Chat.